# With dual monitor in Ubuntu 12.04 the second monitor don't "refresh" the screen

Tags: 12.04, gnome, radeon, multiple-monitors

To illustrate:

I open two terminals, one on each monitor and run the following command:

```
while true; do date; sleep 1; done
```

The result after a few seconds:

[https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxGFSW8N7gRfM2tWdVNQLVo2b1k/view (my desktop screenshot)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxGFSW8N7gRfM2tWdVNQLVo2b1k/view)

A video with demonstration: https://youtu.be/DO55haXzT9M

The primary monitor (on the right) works fine. The second monitor (on the left) stops the "update" of the screen...

And it happens to everything on the second monitor.

The mouse cursor appears and moves normally. But the "contents" of the windows always "freezes".

I tried some solutions to possible similar problems, but nothing works... :'(

**My environment:**

- Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
- Intel CPU
- Graphics Driver: VESA: CEDAR
- Additional Drivers: ATI/AMD proprietary FGLRX graphics driver (post-release updates).
- GNOME Shell 3.4.1

**xrandr:**

> Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
>
> DFP1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 510mm x 287mm
>
> DFP2 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 510mm x 287mm

**Catalyst Control Center - Display Manager:**

> 1. [DELL U2312HM] AMD Radeon HD 5450 1920 X 1080 75 Hz DV
> 2. [DELL U2312HM] AMD Radeon HD 5450  1920 X 1080 75 Hz DVI

Comment: What happens if you move the "frozen" terminal to the other monitor while everything is running? Does it begin to work again, and then freeze once it is moved back?

Comment: When I move it to the other monitor, it appears normally. In fact, he has never been frozen. Just was  not refreshing the screen visualization on the second monitor.

Comment: @Gary  A video with demonstration: [https://youtu.be/DO55haXzT9M](https://youtu.be/DO55haXzT9M)